# SDL Web 8.5 Publishing Failed Committing Deployment State

Tags: web8, publishingfailed

Trying to publish Pages to filesystem, but few pages are failing with attached error. Kindly assist
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Check content deployer logs, there should be more information why your deployment is failing (cd_core and cd_deployer log files). From your screenshot it seems that multimedia from your page is the issue, but log files will tell you more (set to Debug to get complete picture about what is happening before your error).

Comment: Even not throwing any error in deployer logs

Comment: Do you have any log messages for your transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Its seems the error encountered is similar while publishing from web 8 environment as well . You can try go through the suggestions made here - https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=00262977